# numberOfRowsInSection method with expandable and collapsable sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to implement expandable and collapsable sections in my tableView. I am following a tutorial to do it, but I would need your help. 
`expandedSections` is a `NSMutableIndexSet` and `canCollapseSection` is a `BOOL method` declared as follows:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (section >0) return YES;

    return NO;

}
```

This is the `numberOfRowsInSection` original method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            return 5; // return rows when expanded
        }

        return 1; // only top row showing
    }

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

And this is my updated code for the same method. I have also implemented a `search bar` and `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate the section headers and rows.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else {



        if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])

        {
            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
            {



            id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
                 return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
            }
            return 1;}



    }
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

The app is not crashing, and the sections are shown, but it is not working as expected. May be you could check my code and tell me what is wrong there. 
This is a screenshot from the tableView:
[image]

Comment: What does *"it is not working as expected"* mean here?

Comment: Thank you @TomHarrington. That means for example that the first section always appears different to the other sections. I will put a screenshot in my question to show it to you.

Comment: @TomHarrington, I have included a screenshot in my question, may be it helps you to see the problem.

Comment: Checkout this: https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView it has better support for collapsed/expanded rows. (Based on UITableView so very easy to learn)

Comment: Thank you @mdziadkowiec, but I have checked your proposal and I don't find it as easy to learn as you said. And I should change a lot of my app existing code to implement it.

Comment: @mvasco: `canCollapseSection:` returns `NO` for the first section (section #0), so that will definitely behave different than the other sections ...

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, a solution could be changing the collapseSection as follows? if (section == 0 | section >0) return YES;

Comment: @MartinR, you may say that the numberOfRowsInSection method is correct as I have it implemented, taking into account my code and the original code?

Comment: @mvasco: Well, you could try it :-) But I assume that there is another problem with your method of collapsing sections in combination with a fetched results controller: If numberOfRowsInSection returns 1 (instead of the actual number of rows in that section) and then you would also have to modify the FRC delegate methods (so that they do not call insertRows... or deleteRows... for currently "invisible" rows).

Comment: you are right, there is an error, not crashing the app, that says exactly what you assumed

Comment: @MartinR, would you mind writing an answer, so I could close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From my comments:)*

The reason that the first section appears to different from the other sections is
that your `canCollapseSection` method explicitly returns `NO` for section #0.

There could be another problem in combination with a fetched results controller:
If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 1 for a collapsed section (instead of the actual number of rows in that section) then you would also have to modify the FRC delegate methods (so that they do not call `insertRows...` or `deleteRows...` for currently "invisible" rows).

Comment: would you mind taking a look at that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275986/first-row-not-shown-on-expandable-table-view-sections, there are many views but nobody is making any comments. Thank you

Comment: Please, don't take into account my previous comment, I have deleted the mentioned question. Thank you in any case.